# No tilde on apple wireless keyboard

Tags: keyboard, raspi-config

[image][image]Keyboard model[image: model A1314]
Works fine except that I cannot generate a tilde.
The ~ key gives me a >

Comment: Try pressing "Option + N " Or this link. https://superuser.com/questions/64072/cant-type-tilde-character-in-mac-os-x#:~:text=On%20a%20Mac%2C%20tilde%20can,the%20key%20combination%20Alt%20%2B%205%20.

Comment: Try configuring your system for a US keyboard rather than UK (default) with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the keyboard type to be 'Macintosh' and not GB.

This can be done from the GUI menu or from the raspi-config program (sorry no Pi handy today).

Leave your location and language as GB / English.

Comment: I have the keyboard as Macintosh: 0XKBMODEL=Macintosh
and
XKBLAYOUT' ="us"

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration come back with:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/keyboard-configuration.config: 1: /etc/default/keyboard: 0XKBMODEL=Macintosh: not found.
(I have some screenshots but being a bit new round here I dont know if I can add them

Comment: Can possibly get a Pi up in the morning - the picture is of a U.K. keyboard (pound on the 3 dollar on the 4). Check via raspi-config.  Is your keyboard Bluetooth or usb?  You can add pic via editing the question not in comments.

Comment: No big rush on this. It's a problem I also have with a Mac Aluminium KB on a Pi4 (RaspiOS) I have added a couple of pics although these tell the same story as my earlier comment.

Comment: Is the keyboard option `English (UK, Macintosh)` on the Pi?  I know I set that on a Debian 10 VM.  (No where yet with Pi - mind not good this weekend hence surfing at 4AM).

Comment: I presume by "keyboard option" you mean - /etc/default/keyboard. Where OXKBMODEL=Macintosh
See top pic